# SUMIF offsets SUMAREA by two rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the sumif function in combination with index/match to sum up values from another table by row and column criteria. However, the area in which is summed up is always two rows lower than expected (see picture).

This is the formula:

```
=SUMIF($F:$F,$A4,INDEX($H$3:$J$3,0,MATCH(B$3,$H$3:$J$3,0)))
```

How would I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself, the matrix in the index should be over the whole column:

```
=SUMIF($F:$F,$A4,INDEX($H:$J,0,MATCH(B$3,$H$3:$J$3,0)))
```